# Pass generic of wildcard generic data type in java

Tags: java, generics

I have this classes:

```
public interface DataAccessor<E extends Model, U>

public class Data<T> implements DataMenuItemObservable<T> {
```

this interface:

```
interface Listener<T> {
    void onResponse(T value);
}
```

this methods:

```
public interface DataAccessor<E extends Model, U> extends DataMenuItemObservable<E> {

...

    public DataAccessor<? extends Model, ?> getPrimaryDataAccessor()

    void get(int index, Context context, Listener<Data<E>> listener, ErrorListener errorListener);

...

}
```

and get compiler error on this code:

```
DataAccessor<? extends Model, ?> accessor = db.getPrimaryDataAccessor();
accessor.get(0, this, new DataAccessor.Listener<Data<? extends Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Data<? extends Model> value) {
            }
        }, this);
```

idea says `incompatible types: <anonimous Listener<Data<? extends Model>>> cannot be converted to Listener<Data<CAP#1>>`

I also tried implementing interface with `this` but same error.

How to fix error ?
Is there some acceptable workaround ?

Comment: What's the signature of `DataAccessor.get()`?

Comment: What is `Data`?

Comment: @shmosel It contains come data

Comment: I don't care what it contains. I want to see the type declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the compiler doesn't know whether the two wildcards (`? extends Model`) actually refer to the same type. You can work around this by creating a helper method to capture the type:

```
private <E extends Model> void get(DataAccessor<E, ?> accessor);
    accessor.get(0, this, new DataAccessor.Listener<Data<E>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Data<E> value) {
            //...
        }
    }, this);
}
```

Now call the helper:

```
DataAccessor<? extends Model, ?> accessor = db.getPrimaryDataAccessor();
get(accessor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Shmosel has a good solution. I just want to add that, if you have Java 8, you can use a lambda which can infer the right type, contrary to an anonymous class:

```
DataAccessor<? extends Model, ?> accessor = db.getPrimaryDataAccessor();
accessor.get(0, this, value -> {
        // code
    }, this);
```

Comment: I didn't realize that. Very nice.